# How to encode messagepack DateTime, UUI for Tarantool 2.10+?

Tags: rust, uuid, msgpack, tarantool

With Rust crate RMP [RMP Crate](https://crates.io/crates/rmp) any aproach possible pack messagepack for Tarantool field type `datetime` and `uuid`
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tarantool uses the msgpack extension type with a custom internal representation of datetime and uuid. Currently it doesn't provide an api that module developers can use directly. So if you want to serialize datetime or uuid objects as tarantool compatible msgpack you'll have to implement serialization yourself.

Fortunately this is already implemented in the tarantool crate (of which I am one of the authors). There are [`tarantool::uuid::Uuid`](https://docs.rs/tarantool/latest/tarantool/uuid/struct.Uuid.html) & [`tarantool::datetime::Datetime`](https://github.com/picodata/tarantool-module/blob/320a3506e46738b7abb44804bec772c9a7077b83/tarantool/src/datetime.rs#L31) structs. Although Datetime is only on master branch at the moment. These structs implement `serde::Serialize` & `serde::Deserialize` and can be used with `rmp_serde` crate to produce tarantool compatible msgpack representations.

Here's are a couple of examples:

```rust
let uuid = tarantool::uuid::Uuid::nil();
let mp = rmp_serde::to_vec(&uuid).unwrap();
// mp can be passed to tarantool

let dt: tarantool::datetime::Datetime = time_macros::datetime!(2023-05-12 10:01:42.12345 -3).into();
let mp = rmp_serde::to_vec(&dt).unwrap();
// mp can be passed to tarantool
```

You can also use these structs with other apis from `tarantool` crate, e.g. for inserting values into a space with `tarantool::space::Space::insert`.

Comment: Thank you I already fixted like u explain above Tarantool 
UUID: https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/dev_guide/internals/msgpack_extensions/#the-uuid-type
DateTime: https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/dev_guide/internals/msgpack_extensions/#the-datetime-type
Need provide MessagePack Extension correctly according to officail document of Tarantool e.g. DateTime require Write ext metadata with type 4 and size 16 and UUID Write ext metadata with type 2 and size 16

Comment: Above answered by @gmoshkin using `tarantool` crate as type to our personal struct field will solve problem quick